# How to convert only when subtraction matches?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Imagine you have the following df:

```
d = {'line amount#1': [10, 10], 'line amount#2': [10, 10], 'btw-amount#1': [5, 5],'btw-amount#2': [5,4], 'ExclBTW':[10, 10]}
dfcount = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dfcount

+----+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------+
|    |   line amount#1 |   line amount#2 |   btw-amount#1 |   btw-amount#2 |   ExclBTW |
|----+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------|
|  0 |              10 |              10 |              5 |              5 |        10 |
|  1 |              10 |              10 |              5 |              4 |        10 |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------+
```

What I want is to subtract the btw-amount columns from the line amount columns and see if they equal the exclBTW. When they do, I want to update the line amount values.

First, I want to check whether the line amounts equal the ExclBTW without subtracting:

```
lines = dfcount.filter(like="line am")
btwam = dfcount.filter(like="btw-amount").columns
m = lines.sum(axis=1).ne(dfcount["ExclBTW"].astype(float))

dfcount[lines.columns] = lines.mask(m)
dfcount
```

Now I get the following output:

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------+
|    |   line amount#1 |   line amount#2 |   btw-amount#1 |   btw-amount#2 |   ExclBTW |
|----+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------|
|  0 |             nan |             nan |              5 |              5 |        10 |
|  1 |             nan |             nan |              5 |              4 |        10 |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------+
```

Now it converts to Nan, but how to convert it to the subtracted amount (line amount - btw amount) ONLY if the subtraction equals the ExclBTW column?

Desired output:

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------+
|    |   line amount#1 |   line amount#2 |   btw-amount#1 |   btw-amount#2 |   ExclBTW |
|----+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------|
|  0 |             5   |              5  |              5 |              5 |        10 |
|  1 |             10  |             10  |              5 |              4 |        10 |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------+
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you elaborate on `how to convert it to the subtracted amount (line amount - btw amount) ONLY if the subtraction equals the ExclBTW column?`

Comment: yes ofcourse. I want to convert the line amount value to the new value line amount - btw amount when the subtraction equals the ExclBTW column

I think Mustafa has examined the problem very well. However, when running his code I'm getting the btw-amount instead of the subtraction between the two columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
lines = dfcount.filter(like="line")
btws = dfcount.filter(like="btw")

cond = (lines.sum(1) - btws.sum(1)).eq(dfcount.ExclBTW)

new_lines = np.where(np.c_[cond], btws, lines)

dfcount.loc[:, lines.columns] = new_lines
```

to get

```
   line amount#1  line amount#2  btw-amount#1  btw-amount#2  ExclBTW
0              5              5             5             5       10
1             10             10             5             4       10
```

We form the `cond`ition and then take values from `btws` `where` it is True and `lines` when False. Then we put the result back into `dfcount`. The `np.c_[cond]` part is to force broadcasting of `cond` with respect to `btws` and `lines` row-wise.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this works with the values stated however having problems with float values..

Comment: Do you know how to mitigate this?

Comment: @Max can you elaborate on the problems, is it specifically the floating precision arithmetic? If so, can you try `cond = np.isclose(lines.sum(1) - btws.sum(1), dfcount.ExclBTW)`?

Comment: Yes of course, sorry. That works better However, the value takes the btw-amount value instead of subtracting the btw-amount value from the line amount value in my case.

Comment: So instead of 10-5 =5 it just inserts the value of btw-amount#1 and #2, which is 5 as well but with varying values this becomes wrong

Comment: I tried lines- btws but getting following error:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,1) (5,4) (5,2)

Comment: @Max If you have different number of `line` and `btw` columns, what is your expected output? I guess your last result suggests you have 4 line columns and 2 btw columns. But then what to place in the 4 line columns is my question.

Comment: so they are always equal. I edited your code and added like="line amount" and like="btw-amount". Then I added lines.to_numpy()-btws and now it is working fine. Thank you!

Comment: lines = dfcount.filter(like="line amount").astype(float)
btws = dfcount.filter(like="btw-amount").astype(float)

cond = np.isclose(lines.sum(1) - btws.sum(1), dfcount.ExclBTW)


new_lines = np.where(np.c_[cond], lines.to_numpy()-btws, lines)

dfcount.loc[:, lines.columns] = new_lines

dfcount